# How to get user details(emailid) after successful login in all the pages or component in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to angular and typescript. I have 8 pages including login and registration page in my angular project. I need the user profile data for example its email id in each page. I tried sending email to each component by emit function but it is not reliable as data gets lost whenever we refresh the page. Can anyone suggest me a simple and effective method to get email id in each page/component of my project.

Below is my login.ts file

```
        import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
        import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router'; 
        import { Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
        import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
        import { DataService } from '../services/data.service'
        import {EventtosymptomsService } from '../services/eventtosymptoms.service';
        interface loginInfo
        {
          email: string;
          password: string;
        }
        interface Response{
          result: boolean;
        
        }
        @Component({
          selector: 'app-login',
          templateUrl: './login.component.html',
          styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
        })
        export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
          constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute, private dataService: DataService, private eventService: EventtosymptomsService ) { }
          isShown: boolean = true ; // default will be Patient Login
          
          PemailId:string = "";
          Ppassword:string = "";
          logininfo ={} as loginInfo;
          response = {} as Response;
          error_message:boolean = false;
          sendData:string;
          toggleShow() {
          console.log("In toggle show")
          this.isShown = ! this.isShown;
          this.error_message = false;
          }
         
      patientLogin(patient_emailid: string, patient_password: string)
      {
    
        this.logininfo.email = patient_emailid;
        this.logininfo.password = patient_password;
        console.log(this.logininfo)
        this.sendData = patient_emailid;
        this.loginCheckPatient()
        
      }
    
      Register()
      {
        console.log("hello")
        this.router.navigate(['register']);
    
      }
            loginCheckPatient() {
                this.dataService.loginCheck(this.logininfo)
                  .subscribe(data => {
                    console.log(data)
                    this.response = data;
                    if(this.response.result)
                  {
                    console.log("In response check", this.response["result"])
                    this.error_message = false
                    this.eventService.emit<{}>(this.sendData);
                    this.router.navigate(['analyseSymptoms']);
                  }
                  else{
                        console.log("In else")
                          this.error_message = true;
                  }
                  }
                  )
                  
              }
}
```

Below is my service code file (dataservice.ts)

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
    import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
    import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
    import { ajax } from 'rxjs/ajax';
    
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class DataService {
     
      loginPatient_url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/loginPatient"

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }
  loginCheck(person): Observable<any> {
    const headers = { 'content-type': 'application/json'}  
    const body=JSON.stringify(person);
    console.log(body)
    return this.httpClient.post(this.loginPatient_url , body,{'headers':headers})
  }
}
```

Comment: You can store it in localstorage or cookie and use a service to access it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Behavior Subject
The BehaviorSubject holds the value that needs to be shared with other components.
These components subscribe to data which is simple returning the BehaviorSubject value without the functionality to change the value.
Here is a more detailed breakdown of asObservable. In updateDataSelection we call next and pass in a new value to the BehaviorSubject.
Create a service first like below

```
`import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

import { loginInfo } from '../entities/data';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  private dataSource = new BehaviorSubject<loginInfo>(new loginInfo());
  data = this.dataSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  updatedDataSelection(data: loginInfo){
    this.dataSource.next(data);
  }
  
}`

Use above service in all the components where you want user details

`//inject service into component

dataService.data.subscribe(data => {
  //do what ever needs doing when data changes
})

//update the value of data in the service
dataService.updateData(newData);
```